# PHP copying or moving uploaded file - nothing happens, but no error

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm not getting the file copied either:

```
$upload_folder = "uploads/";

$name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

$prefix = date("YmdHis");
$path_of_uploaded_file = "$upload_folder$prefix-$name_of_uploaded_file";
$tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];

if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
{
  if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
  {
    $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
  }
}

echo $path_of_uploaded_file;
echo $name_of_uploaded_file;
echo $errors;
```

This worked fine on a Windows development environment, but deploying to a Linux web server is doing this.  We were getting a copying error initially, then we added permissions to the uploads directory.  Now we get nothing.

I've also tried this with move_uploaded_file, no errors, but no resulting file in the uploads directory.

Comment: Are you completely sure the file path is correct?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski We echoed it out (and it works on Windows) - it shows the full path and the base name is fine.  Also we echoed out the $tmp_path and that seemed fine (but we never seem to be quick enough to see the file appear - I assume it has a very short lifespan).  If the file wasn't there in tmp, we should see a copy error, I would think?

Comment: Do you have a `MAX_FILE_SIZE` input in your form? You probably do, so try setting the value to `0` (zero).

Comment: I hope you have some serious validation going on before this code hits. Letting the user name uploaded files can be a big security hole.

Comment: Try to use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`. Maybe that helps. Additionally, you should enable error reporting, for debugging: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);` on top of the upload-script file. You should see warnings if files can not be moved then.

Comment: @hakre Same results with move_uploaded_file - no error and no file in uploads directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can add a check if is_uploaded_file returns true.

```
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
{
  if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
  {
    $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
  }
} else {
    $errors .= '\n error while uploading file'; // maybe  upload_max_filesize exceeded
// try to get the specific error

 switch($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']){
    case 0: //no error; possible file attack!
      echo "There was a problem with your upload.";
      break;
    case 1: //uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini
      echo "The file you are trying to upload is too big.";
      break;
    case 2: //uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the html form
      echo "The file you are trying to upload is too big.";
      break;
    case 3: //uploaded file was only partially uploaded
      echo "The file you are trying upload was only partially uploaded.";
      break;
    case 4: //no file was uploaded
      echo "You must select an image for upload.";
      break;
    default: //a default error, just in case!  :)
      echo "There was a problem with your upload.";
      break;

}
```

maybe your upload_max_filesize exceeded, or there is another server setting that does not allow the upload.

see [php dokumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) for more infos on possible problems.

Comment: `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']` is 0, `is_uploaded_file($tmp_path)` is true

Comment: Ok, but now we know at least can be sure that the upload itself worked. I guess you already tried to dump the $_FILES variable, $tmp_path variable and $path_of_uploaded_file variable and check if the files are there on the filesystem? I guess there may be a problem with the location of the uploaded files, e.g. did you try to call the realpath function on the fielnames and check if they are correct?

Comment: Dumped name, type, tmp_name, error, size - all look good.  Let's see what realpath gives.  (Needless to say, PHP is something new for me).

Comment: Ok, if you already tried Hakre's comment and you do not get any error - it should have worked - so I would guess the file has been uploaded, just not to the location we are searching for it. Let me know if you were able to solve the problem. Good luck

Comment: The file was apparently uploading, but screen was not refreshing even when we asked for it to refresh...  `realpath` did help us see that `realpath($tmp_path)` was good before the move and bad afterwards, while `realpath` displayed the opposite behavior for the output path.

Answer (score 1):

```
$upload_folder = "uploads/";
$path_of_uploaded_file = "$upload_folder$prefix-$name_of_uploaded_file";
```

Make Your `$path_of_uploaded_file` to be

```
$path_of_uploaded_file = "$upload_folder/$prefix-$name_of_uploaded_file";
```